# img src not working with php and php variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
foreach ($values as $value)
    {

        echo("<td> "."<img src= \"$value[\"img\"]\" />"."</td>"); 
        print("</tr>");
    }
```

I am basically trying to print the image whose path I've stored in mysql database. However I am getting very confused with the img src in html and after trying a lot of ways, the image is still not being printed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're escaping too many times. just be simple about it:

```
echo '<td><img src="'.$value['img'].'"/></td>';
```

You could also do it this way:

```
echo "<td><img src='{$value['img']}' /></td>";
```

Answer (score -1):

I've corrected your code.

```
foreach ($values as $value)
    {

        echo("<td> "."<img src='".$value["img"]."' />"."</td>"); 
        print("</tr>");
    }
```